# C++ operator << overloading for std::vector with separate declaration / definition ok for template but not for concrete type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, stdvector

I want to overload the `<<` operator to print vectors. This works fine for template arguments `vector<T>` (with explicit template instantiations) but not for a concrete `vector<complex<double>>` argument when the code is split into a declaration in foo.h and a definition in foo.cpp.

So while this works:

```
// foo.h

template < typename T >
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector< T >& v);


// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h" // and using directives

template < typename T >
inline ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const vector< T >& v ) 
{
    os << "[";
    for (auto vv : v) os << " " << vv;
    os << " ]";

    return os;
}

template ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const vector< double >& v); // double

template ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const vector< int >& v); // int
```

When adding to the header a `vector<complex<double>>` argument variant

```
// foo.h
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v)
```

and the implementation to the source

```
// foo.cpp
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v) 
{   
    os << "[";
    for (auto vv : v)
        os << " ( " << vv.real() << ((vv.imag() >= 0 ) ? " +" : " ") << vv.imag() << "i )";
    os << " ]";
    return os;
}
```

I get the error

> undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > const&)`

when trying to call that operator

**If I move the implementation to the header file, the code works.**

Since the whole type, i.e `complex<double>` is known, I didn't treat the last operator overload as templated but rather as a "regular" thing (there is no "pattern" to fill in for the compiler, isn't it?) 
But even when I treat it as a specialized template

```
template< >
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v);
```

it does not work.

The answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700941/best-way-to-specialise-operator-for-stdostream-and-stdvector-with-generic) says to simply NOT overload the vector type but it doesn't explain the above mentioned behavior and I am curious about *why* this happens.

Comment: are you sure that you really compiled an linked against 'foo.cpp'? the symptom are the same if you forgot about it.

Comment: You are not linking against the cpp file. The compiler cannot find the implementation for that function, which is why you're getting that error. Are you including foo.h?

Comment: This is a dead end - in practical terms, you can't add operator overloads where the only operands are built-in types or members of `namespace std`.  This is because overloaded operators should be findable by ADL, but yours will not be since it is not in `namespace std`. (And it's UB to add your code to namespace std).