# How to take vector as input in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, input

I need to take a vector as an input in a C++ program.

The following is my code:

```
int main() {
        vector<int> nums;
        int target;
        
        cin >> nums;
        cin >> target;
        
        Solution mine;
        mine.twoSum(nums,target);
}
```

And following is the error shown by the compiler:

```
Line 32: Char 13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'vector<int>')
        cin >> nums;
        ~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

Comment: You need to read the numbers in one at a time, and add them to the vector.

Comment: `int tmp; cin >> tmp; nums.push_back(tmp)` ?

Comment: How do you know which number should go in `target`?

Comment: In the OPs example, one line would need to be space delimited numbers, the second line would be a single int.

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample input, in plain text (no images).  Format as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine how to distinguish between elements, and also where the end is.

E.g. if you read `int`s until there are none left in the input, you will have read in the value intended for `target`.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T, A> & vec) 
{
    for(T value;/* you need to define this condition*/ && (is >> value);) 
    {
        vec.push_back(std::move(value));
    }
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Such an operator would cause [lookup problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700941/best-way-to-specialise-operator-for-stdostream-and-stdvector-with-generic), and in general should be avoided.

Comment: @IgorR. only when it is used before it is defined

Comment: Whenever it should be found via ADL.

Comment: @IgorR. [Not all lookup is ADL](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f403910a1bbd696)

Comment: Of course. But *whenever* it should be looked-up with ADL (eg. within a template context), you've got a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You're attempting to read `nums` directly from `std::cin` with the operator `>>`. There isn't any overload of the operator  for `operator>>` that takes a `std::ostream` (`std::cin` type) and `std::vector<int>` (`nums`'s type), so there is a type error.

**Solution:**

You have to read each number and push one by one to the vector.

**Example code:**

Here there is an example where the last number goes to `target` and the rest to the `nums`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void readVectorFromStdCin(std::vector<int>& to_read)
{
    for(int n; std::cin >> n;)
        to_read.push_back(n);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int target;

    readVectorFromStdCin(nums);
    target = nums[nums.size()-1];
    nums.pop_back();

    Solution mine;
    mine.twoSum(nums,target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to take vector as input in C++?

`std::cin` has no overload that takes a vector

---

I suggest that you read the first line of input (assuming space separated) into a string and then the `target` afterwards

```
std::string line;
int         target;

std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::cin >> target;
```

You can then create a string stream out of the first line

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
```

And then create a vector using the constructor that takes two iterators

```
std::vector<int> nums(std::istream_iterator<int>{ iss },
                      std::istream_iterator<int>{});
```