# Stream insertion operator >> for std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17, iostream, stdoptional

Is there a reasonably idiomatic way* to use stream insertion operators `>>` with `std::optional`? The standard class does not provide an overload for `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::optional<T>& obj)`, and I believe using

```cpp
std::optional<int> i{};
stream >> *i;
```

invokes undefined behavior if `i` does not already have a value.

*Yes I am aware that nothing about streams is idiomatic or natural...

Comment: The dark side of the Stream is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be ... unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. `*i` is undefined behavior for an empty `std::optional`.
What you should do instead is:

```cpp
auto i = [&stream] -> std::optional<int> {
    int result;
    if (stream >> result) return result;
    else return {};
}();
```

Instead of an immediately-invoked lambda expression (IILE), you could also write a utility function that does this for you:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> try_read(std::istream& stream) {
    T result;
    if (stream >> result) return result;
    else return {};
}

// ...
std::optional<int> i = try_read<int>(stream);
```

Comment: Since we have C++17, it can be shortened to `if (T result; stream >> result) ...`, so you don't have to write that lambda for the sake of having a scope to destroy `result` early.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen can you explain what you mean about not needing a lambda?

Comment: @kc9jud I assumed at first that the "immediately-invoked lambda expression" is there to have a scope in which `result` exists and doesn't leak, but now I see there's also the added benefit of initialising the optional with the result (instead of reassigning it in `if` body). I just don't like this idiom (it's super hard to notice that function call immediately after lambda, especially when `auto` is in play), so I'd rather do anything to avoid it :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Ah, I see -- this is trying to exploit NVRO?

Comment: @kc9jud neither my IILE version nor the if statement benefit from NRVO. The return type of the lambda is `std::optional`, and `result` gets converted from `int` to `std::optional<int>` which produces a prvalue. So there's plain old copy elision/RVO, no NRVO for this returned object.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@Jan Schultke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740428/jan-schultke)'s answer, one could also provide a definition for `operator>>`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::optional<T>& obj)
{
    if (T result; is >> result) obj = result;
    else obj = {};
    return is;
}

//...
std::optional<int> i;
std::cin >> i;
```

<s>However, it is unclear to me if defining such a function which acts purely on Standard Library types is allowed by the Standard. (At least here `operator>>` is not in the `std::` namespace.)</s> It seems that doing this is allowed, but may be a [questionable practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701053/2088857).

Comment: It's allowed to define overloads like this. It's only disallowed to define specializations of templates that don't contain at least one user-defined type, but this isn't specializing anything.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yeah, I think it's allowed, but may be in poor taste: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701053/2088857

Just because you _can_, doesn't mean you _should_.

Comment: Perfectly fine to define that in the global namespace, or your own namespace. 
 You're not allowed to define that operator in the `std` namespace.  (Where "not allowed" has a big dollop of "please, don't do that".)  And when ADL is being used, it won't find that operator because it's in the the "wrong" namespace.  (:sad_panda:)